# Issues with 2D Body/Limb system

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, matrix, skeletal-animation

In my game I have programmed **Body** and **Limb** classes. The Body is guaranteed to have an origin in the center of its sprite. The Body class has a List of children Limbs, each with their own offset. Every Limb has a **Master** value which references the parent *Body*, but it also has a **Parent** value which *references the Limb it is a child of*. However, Limbs do not have to have a parent, they can directly connect to the Body.

The **Master**, **Parent**, and **Children** values of the **Limb** class:

```
    //Body containing all limbs this limb is connected to and others.
    public Body Master
    { get; set; }

    //Parent limb, if null then limb directly connected to the body.
    public Limb Parent
    { get; set; }

    //Children limbs
    public List<Limb> Children
    { get; set; }
```

The Limb methods have if statements to handle these situations. In relation to the offsets and rotations of the Limbs around the Body (using transformation matrices) things seem to work fine. Now, the problem I'm having is when a Limb is attached to another Limb. The child Limb draws and behaves as if it is rotating around the Body instead of its parent Limb, and the parent Limb itself vanishes. Limbs without Children that are directly connected to the Master Body have **no issues**. Because of this sort of recursive hierarchy I believe the problem has to do with reference types but I may be mistaken. Here is some additional code:

**Demonstration:**

[image]

Here is the **worldPosition()** method which is used to acquire the Limb's position in world space. I suspect it may be the culprit. The **Master.Position** is already in world space:

```
    public Vector2 worldPosition()
    {
        if (Parent != null) return (LocalPosition += Parent.worldPosition());
        else return (LocalPosition += Master.Position);
    }
```

Finally here is the **Update()** method of the Limb class:
http://pastebin.com/5L5v5p6x

**EDIT:** Upon further analysis it appears that any changes I make to either Limb seem to affect the other Limb in one way or another even though they are both quite clearly different instances.

Here is the code to make the initial Body and first Limb:

```
        b = new Body()
        {
            Sprite = FileFactory.Textures["shoulders"],
            Position = new Vector2(this.Position.X, this.Position.Y),
        };

        Limb l = new Limb()
        {
            Sprite = FileFactory.Textures["left_arm"],
            Master = b,
            Offset = new Vector2(2, 13),
            Origin = new Vector2(0, Sprite.Height / 2),
            RotationalDifference = (float)(0.2 * Math.PI),
            RotateSpeed = 0.15f
        };

        b.Children.Add(l);
        b.Initialize();
```

And the code to add the child Limb to the first (Parent) Limb:

```
            Children.Add(
            new Limb()
            {
                Sprite = FileFactory.Textures["right_arm"],
                Master = this.Master,
                Parent = this,
                Offset = new Vector2(27, 0),
                Origin = new Vector2(0, Sprite.Height / 2),
                RotationalDifference = (float)(0.2 * Math.PI),
                RotateSpeed = 0.15f
            }
            );
```

Comment: Standard-ish debugging questions: What's the simplest case that still works? What's the simplest that breaks?

Comment: The simplest case that works is when the Limbs don't have children. Suddenly when a child is added to a limb it breaks so that would be the simplest case that breaks.

Comment: You can simplify futher to isolate further: What happens when you do super-simple rendering (like just drawing lines or untransformed sprites)?

Comment: Well I commented out the lines that transform the Limbs and even the child Limb vanishes after that. Now there is no arm whatsoever.

Comment: When I comment out the code that adds the new child Limb to the Limb directly attached to the Body, the Limb directly attached to the body reappears. This is part of the reason why I think worldPosition() is the culprit because of the way it works, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem is in this code here:

```
public Vector2 worldPosition()
{
    if (Parent != null) return (LocalPosition += Parent.worldPosition());
    else return (LocalPosition += Master.Position);
}
```

I was using the wrong operator, += instead of just +. I was continually adding one position to the other and returning the accumulating result. It's hilarious that it took somebody else to notice it and only after 2 days of the problem arising. The working code looks like this:

```
public Vector2 worldPosition()
{
    if (Parent != null) return (LocalPosition + Parent.worldPosition());
    else return (LocalPosition + Master.Position);
}
```